# How to add a percentage column to each dataset of a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, frequency, percentage

I have this dataset (let's imagine it with 900 variables ) and the list l2 as follows :

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1), y = c(2,2,2,2,3,3,2) )

l1 = lapply(df,table)

l2 = lapply(l1,as.data.frame)
```

I wish to add a percentage column to each of these dataframes based on the `Freq` column of each dataframe. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `proportions`:

```r
lapply(df, \(x) transform(as.data.frame(table(x)), prop = proportions(Freq)))
```

```r
$x
  x Freq      prop
1 0    3 0.4285714
2 1    4 0.5714286

$y
  x Freq      prop
1 2    5 0.7142857
2 3    2 0.2857143
```

Comment: Try `base::transform`

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
proportions(table(data.frame(nm1 = names(df)[col(df)], val = unlist(df))), 1)
```

-output

```
val
nm1         0         1         2         3
  x 0.4285714 0.5714286 0.0000000 0.0000000
  y 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.7142857 0.2857143
```